# Exoplayer stops looping

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using exoplayer with looping feature as following:

```
private fun prepareExoPlayerFromFileUri(uri: Uri, mediaView: SurfaceView) {
    val exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(DefaultRenderersFactory(this), DefaultTrackSelector(null as BandwidthMeter?), DefaultLoadControl())
    exoPlayer.setVideoSurfaceView(mediaView)

    val dataSpec = DataSpec(uri)
    val fileDataSource = FileDataSource()
    try {
        fileDataSource.open(dataSpec)
    } catch (e: FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    val factory = DataSource.Factory { fileDataSource }
    val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource(fileDataSource.uri, factory, DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null)

    exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
    exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
    exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
}
```

However, after sometime I observe that the video has just stopped at the very last frame.
I can't see anything in logs related to exoplayer.

Here is my setup:

Asus Tinkerboard with Marshmellow and a tv connected via HDMI port. Screen is always on.

Edit: I have created an issue on ExoPlayer repo:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3239

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though this was caused by an audio track that was shorter than the video track, and the current version of ExoPlayer, at that time, would hang because of this.

The ExoPlayer team addressed this in [issue 1874](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1874), which was published in ExoPlayer 2.6.0, so this shouldn't happen on the latest versions any longer.